# Pointer and malloc in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, malloc, alloc

I am trying to convert [this](https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest) into swift.

Facing issue at memory allocation logic

```
Byte *p[10000];

p[allocatedMB] = malloc(1048576);
memset(p[allocatedMB], 0, 1048576);
```

How to write this in swift?

Comment: To expand on Martin's answer (+1), I might also encourage the use of Swift feature `_` to make those big numbers more readable, e.g. `malloc(1_048_576)`, to make it easier to read at a glance.

Comment: ... or in this case, `1024*1024`

Comment: See "[“Please convert my code to X” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54345/please-convert-my-code-to-x-questions)"

Comment: **See for example: [Swift way to convert Data to Hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69477135/edit)** (which uses `UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `malloc` from Swift, it returns a "raw pointer":

```
var p: [UnsafeMutableRawPointer?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: 10000)
var allocatedMB = 0

p[allocatedMB] = malloc(1048576)
memset(p[allocatedMB], 0, 1048576)
```

Alternatively, use `UnsafeMutablePointer` and its
`allocate` and `initialize` methods:

```
var p: [UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: 10000)
var allocatedMB = 0

p[allocatedMB] = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1048576)
p[allocatedMB]?.initialize(to: 0, count: 1048576)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! Could you please let me know the resources or example to learn more about UnsafeMutableRawPointer in swift?

Comment: I am using first way (using malloc) - Getting "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" message on debugger after allocation of around 600MB. Total available memory is 1.96GB.

Comment: using both way userMemory is not increasing after allocating 1 object. I am repeatedly allocating memory by using this code snippet in loop.