# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue #1

Tags: swift, pointers, memory

I am trying to simulate memory warning in ios project. But when used memory reaches to around 600 MB I am getting **"Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue #1"** on debugger.
Same is working on objective C.
Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725722/pointer-and-malloc-in-swfit/48725872#48725872)
question for more details.
I have tried by both ways as described by @Martin R.

I am using a timer to allocate 1MB memory in every 1 second to allocate all the available memory in iPHone and generate memory warning.

Here is the objective C  code using malloc

`p[allocatedMB] = malloc(1048576);
 memset(p[allocatedMB], 0, 1048576);
 allocatedMB += 1;`

Comment: Please show both the Objective-C and the Swift code. There should be no difference when using malloc from those languages.

Comment: Yes there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator has a command for this: `Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning` (Cmd-Shift-M).

On the device, try

```
UIApplication.shared.perform(Selector(("_performMemoryWarning")))
```

(and don't forget to remove this code when submitting to the App Store)

Comment: I want to generate it on device.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, But I already tried it. Now want to allocate memory iteratively and check app behaviour. That's why trying to write this. It will not crash the but if it happens in real time app would crash after 1-2 warnings.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why this code is working in objective c and crashing in swift. Check here if you find something - https://github.com/Split82/iOSMemoryBudgetTest